# How can I connect C# with Db with App.config?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, app-config

I need to connect C# with SQL Server database using `app.config`.

My code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string  connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;     

    public Form1()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InsertDeleteUpdate(string query)
    {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Succeeded");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
            }
        }
```

and in `app.config` I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test1" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=KSPR1WS126;Initial Catalog=Test1;User ID=sa" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but I get an error and I can't fix it:

> ConfigurationErrorExeption was Unhandled  Configuration system
>   failed to initialize

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: You do not seem to be referring to the correct key in the App.config file. In your code you try to read a connection string named "Conn", while the one you configured is called "Test1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test1"].ConnectionString;
```

You're referencing `Conn` as the connection string name but referenced it as `Test1` in the `App.Config`

Answer (score 2):

Try below code and then check

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test1"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Conn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Data Source=KSPR1WS126;Initial Catalog=Test1;User ID=sa" />
  </connectionStrings>
```